# switch case statement of oracle sql to decide which query to execute

Tags: sql, oracle, switch-statement

Based on the column value, I need to execute 2 different queries in Oracle sql.

Table A

```
Col1   Col2
R51    desc_r51
R52    desc_r52
R53    desc_r53
```

Table B

```
Col1   Type     Username
R51    All      A
R52    Specific B
```

Now i need to write a query, where

- if Type is All in Table B, get **all values of Col1** from Table A
- if Type is Specific in Table B, get **only values which are matching
  Col1 of Table A and Table B**

So in this case, if Type is All then the result should be
R51, R52, R53

If Type is Specific, then the result should be
R52

Any help?

Comment: Sound like you need an storeprocedure with parameters. `CASE` evaluate expresion and generate a value. Doesnt work as flow control.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why not just: `SELECT  * FROM    table_b b inner join table_a a on (a.col1 = b.col1 AND b.type = 'Specific') OR b.type = 'All'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select A.col1
  from A
 where exists (select 1 from B where type = 'All')
 union 
select  B.col1
  from A, B
 where A.Col1 = B.Col1 and
       B.Type = 'Specific'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this.

```
SELECT 'SELECT '
       ||CASE
           WHEN TYPE = 'All' THEN (SELECT Listagg(col1, ',')
                                            within GROUP ( ORDER BY col1 )
                                   FROM   tablea)
           WHEN TYPE = 'Specific'
                AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM   tablea a
                            WHERE  a.col1 = b.col1) THEN b.col1
         END
       ||' FROM TABLEA;' as select_statement
FROM   tableb b;
```

**Output :**

```
SELECT_STATEMENT
SELECT R51,R52,R53 FROM TABLEA;
SELECT R52 FROM TABLEA;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89872/11/0